# why mybatis has selectOne and selectList together

Tags: java, mybatis

I intended to design a method `public List<Booking> getBooking(Integer id)` to get booking, I think it is enough. But my co-worker said I should create two methods

`public Booking getBooking(Integer id)` 
and `public List<Booking> getBookingList(Map parameter)`,

he said we should be and also mentioned mybatis has `selectOne` and `selectList` at the same time too.

I checked the `selectOne` and `selectList` of `DefaultSqlSession` of mybatis, found that it just call the selectList in selectOne and return the first if selectList has one result, otherwise return null or throw an exception.

Hence, I think that there is no strong reason to both have selectOne and selectList.

Therefore my questions are:

1. Why mybatis has selectOne and selectList rather than selectList only
2. Is it a convention or good practice to do that like mybatis, that is when we want to get object, we need to design two methods, one is used to get one object, another is used to get list object

Comment: Although you have a good question, I voted to close because of Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. And your's is particularly dependent on the designer of MyBatis choices.

Comment: Do you realize that `selectOne()` throwing an exception and `selectList()` returning empty list have different semantics? What if I store a singleton entity in the table, and finding two or more rows means something went very wrong? That's exactly the situation where I'd use `selectOne()`. Returning `null` on missing result is debatable though; in JPA, for example, `NoResultException` is that case. But the overall idea is the same - to report three possible outcomes - found/not-found/ambiguous.

Comment: @JorgeCampos hibernate also has this case, so I don't know it is a convention or good practice to do that or not, therefore I asked question here

Comment: @yegodm thanks for your answer, yes your are correct, I thought this reason and want to see there is other reasons or not

Answer (score 0):

Your class shouldn't have

```
public Booking getBooking()
```

That doesn't make much sense: which of the bookings in the database would it return?

It should, however, have

```
public Booking getBooking(Long id)
```

which makes a lot of sense: it allows getting the unique booking identified by the given ID. Such a query would be useful in a whole lot of usecases (displaying the booking, editing the booking, etc.). And much more, actually, than `getBookings()`, which would return all bookings: you really don't want, and there shouldn't be any no good reason in general, to load all the bookings in your database.

Now, why does myBatis have both kinds of methods? Because many queries are supposed to return only one value, and using a method that returns a list when executing such a query would be cumbersome: you would systematically have to test if the list is empty, and get its first element.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I ignored the parameters just for simplicity, I added it back now